# Issue with QR code generated by Google Charts

Tags: javascript, url, google-visualization, qr-code

I am working on generating QR code containing URL to my website. Along with URL, I have to pass some data to the page. As the traditional method, I appended the `#` followed by the data after my website URL

Eg: `http://www.testing1234.com#myTestingData`

Then converted the url(string) into QR code using Google charts. But during this process, the QR code is generated for the string `http://www.testing1234.com` only. What written after the `'#'` is not reading while generating QR code

I am following [Google Infographics](https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/docs/qr_codes) documentation
What I have tried is,

```js
var cert_link = "http://www.testing1234.com#myTestingData";
var qr = "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=350x350&cht=qr&chl="+cert_link;
```

I have expected the output QR code with the full string `cert_link`. But what I am getting is a QR code with only data `"http://www.testing1234.com"`

I don't understand what I am missing here. How to solve this? Or is there any alternative solution for this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to URL encode the `#` to `%23`.

In JavaScript, use [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

```
var cert_link = encodeURIComponent("http://www.testing1234.com#myTestingData");
var qr = "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=350x350&cht=qr&chl="+cert_link+";
```

That will turn your link into `http%3A%2F%2Fwww.testing1234.com%23myTestingData` and Google will be able to generate a QR code from it.